# How to make an array of "types.Add()"

Tags: c#, arrays, excel, types

I am not sure if my title is right, But I want to make an array of this:

`(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet)newWorkbook_First.Sheets.Add();`

Now this is what I thought that had to happen:

```
private static Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass appExcel;
private static Workbook newWorkbook_First = null;
private static _Worksheet newSheets = null;
newSheets =  new (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet)newWorkbook_First.Sheets.Add()[];
```

But this didn't solve the problem. How do I make an array of the type?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want an array of `_Worksheet` based on your cast.

```
newSheets = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet[];
```

**Note:** As I see from your code `newWorkbook_First.Sheets.Add()` is a method and you can't create an instance of a method.

Comment: I declare the newSheets as : `private static _Worksheet newSheets = null;` But it will give me this error after I put ur code in: ` Cannot implicitly convert type 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet[]' to 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet' 
`

Comment: I added some importnt code to my question now @ardicadar

Comment: That's happening because `private static _Worksheet newSheets = null;` this is not an array, if you want an array it must be like this `private static _Worksheet[] newSheets = null;`. Notice the `[]` added.

Comment: So I cannot add multiple sheets, like 100, in a short code? @adricadar

Comment: @wouter You can `Add` multiple sheets to an existing collection. You can either do `newSheets = newWorkbook_First.Sheets` this will contains all sheets. Or you can add them after you create the array.

Comment: Sorry I dont really get it. this is what I have now but its giving me a nullexpection when I run it. `newSheets = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet[5];
                newSheets = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet[])newWorkbook_First.Sheets[1];`

Comment: I can also add sheets this way, where the 5 stands for how many sheets to make, but I have no idea how to call the sheets 1by1: `newSheet2 = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet)newWorkbook_First.Sheets.Add(Type.Mis‌​sing,Type.Missing,5,Type.Missing); ` @adricadar

Comment: @wouter You ge the NullException because this is null `newWorkbook_First = null;`

Comment: No I dont think so.Becase when I put this code instead: `(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet)newWorkbook_First.Sheets.Add(Type.Mis‌​‌​sing,Type.Missing,5,Type.Missing);` I dont get the nullexpection